# Comparing two rows in oracle without using lead and lag functions

Tags: sql, oracle

how to compare two rows in a same table without using lead/lag functions in oracle?

I tried the self join of the table and using row number function but it didnt work for me.

suppose table is T1 and the data is stored in the format as mentioned below.

```
ID  Name    Address     Date
1   A       Noida       10-Apr-2019
1   A       Gurugram    15-Apr-2019
1   A       Mumbai      18-Apr-2019
```

and i want the output data to be like.

```
ID  Name    Old_value   New_value   Date
1   A                   Noida       10-Apr-2019
1   A       Noida       Gurugram    15-Apr-2019
1   A       Gurugram    Mumbai      18-Apr-2019
```

Comment: And what's wrong with `LEAD` and `LAG`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get good answers, please review: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe). - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (id, name, address, cdate) as
  2    (select 1, 'A', 'Noida'   , date '2019-04-10' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'A', 'Gurugram', date '2019-04-15' from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'A', 'Mumbai'  , date '2019-04-18' from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select t.*,
  8            row_number() over (partition by name order by cdate) rn
  9     from test t
 10    )
 11  select a.id, a.name, b.address old_value, a.address new_value, a.cdate
 12  from temp a left join temp b on a.id = b.id and a.rn = b.rn + 1
 13  order by a.cdate;

        ID N OLD_VALU NEW_VALU CDATE
---------- - -------- -------- ----------
         1 A          Noida    10.04.2019
         1 A Noida    Gurugram 15.04.2019
         1 A Gurugram Mumbai   18.04.2019

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use window functions, you can do it with a subquery:

```
select
  t.ID, t.Name,
  (select Address from tablename 
   where ID = t.ID 
   and "Date" = (
     select max("Date") 
     from tablename 
     where ID = t.ID and "Date" < t."Date"
   )
  ) Old_value,
  t.Address New_value,
  t."Date"
from tablename t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=66df913ec05d719b40be671877ac70ca).
Results:

```
> ID | NAME | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE | Date     
> -: | :--- | :-------- | :-------- | :--------
>  1 | A    |           | Noida     | 10-APR-19
>  1 | A    | Noida     | Gurugram  | 15-APR-19
>  1 | A    | Gurugram  | Mumbai    | 18-APR-19
```

Answer (score 0):

In future questions, I strongly recommend:

- Providing test data using CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements
- Sharing your precise Oracle database version number.

Starting with version 12c, you can use row pattern matching:

```
with test (id, name, address, cdate) as
(select 1, 'A', 'Noida'   , date '2019-04-10' from dual union all
 select 1, 'A', 'Gurugram', date '2019-04-15' from dual union all
 select 1, 'A', 'Mumbai'  , date '2019-04-18' from dual
)
select * from test
match_recognize(
  partition by id, name order by cdate
  measures prev(address) old_address
  all rows per match
  pattern(a)
  define a as 1=1
);

ID   NAME   CDATE                  OLD_ADDRESS   ADDRESS    
 1   A      2019-04-10 00:00:00                  Noida       
 1   A      2019-04-15 00:00:00    Noida         Gurugram    
 1   A      2019-04-18 00:00:00    Gurugram      Mumbai
```